To combine timeline and line chart
I have two distinct datasets in Power BI:
Source 1: (top)
•   Date (not aligned with Source2)
•   Count1, Count2, Countn (Also legend for the counts)
Source 2: (bottom)
•   Date (non-continuous)
•   Symptom Text
•   Technician Text
I want to visualize both datasets on the same chart, aligning them based on their respective dates. How can I achieve this effectively in Power BI without overlaying two different charts? I need to display both text data (Symptom Text, Technician Text) and count data (Count1, Count2) on the same time base (Date)/X axis without converting text into numerical values.
Can anyone suggest the best approach or visualization for achieving this?

I tried to do 2 different chart but I want everything in single chart.
